# AWS Structure: can NGINX be NAT?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, nat

I working on my project structure based on AWS. 
And figure out the best suitable for me:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/images/aeb-vpc-rds-topo.png

But all my instances running thought NGINX locally. I'm using NGINX as proxy.

Can i switch NAT for NGINX in this scheme? 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/images/aeb-vpc-rds-topo.png

In other words - do NGINX capable to do what NAT do? Or should i remove NGINX from my Instances and use other proxy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nginx cannot be NAT, because NAT is a translation happening in L3 layer of an OSI model (IP packet header addresses are rewritten), and nginx works way above - on L7.

Answer (score 2):

Nginx cannot be NAT, but [AWS recently launched NAT-as-a-Service](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-managed-nat-network-address-translation-gateway-for-aws/) so you don't have to host your own servers for this.

Comment: Fixed your link.

Comment: looks great! will try this one